# Finding the source of a failed static assertion on Eigen

Tags: c++, static, assert, eigen

I'm trying to compile a -quite large- code base which has some dependencies to Eigen. Doing so, I got the following error: `error C2338: THE_BRACKET_OPERATOR_IS_ONLY_FOR_VECTORS__USE_THE_PARENTHESIS_OPERATOR_INSTEAD` that originates here:

```
//    Eigen\src\Core\DenseCoeffsBase.h


/** \returns a reference to the coefficient at given index.
  *
  * This method is allowed only for vector expressions, and for matrix expressions having the LinearAccessBit.
  *
  * \sa operator[](Index) const, operator()(Index,Index), x(), y(), z(), w()
  */

EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE Scalar&
operator[](Index index)
{
  #ifndef EIGEN2_SUPPORT
  EIGEN_STATIC_ASSERT(Derived::IsVectorAtCompileTime,
                      THE_BRACKET_OPERATOR_IS_ONLY_FOR_VECTORS__USE_THE_PARENTHESIS_OPERATOR_INSTEAD)
  #endif
  eigen_assert(index >= 0 && index < size());
  return derived().coeffRef(index);
}
```

As the Eigen dependencies are all over the code, how can I find the line triggering this error? (obviously, there is a line of code accessing an Eigen matrix using `[]`, *somewhere*, this is the line I'm looking for).

Comment: Look more carefully at the compiler messages: you should see the complete call stack at the origin of the issue.

Comment: @ggael There isn't anything else.

Comment: I see that you are using MSVC, just after the error line, you should see several lines containing `see reference to function template instantiation` showing you the context that triggered the error.  If you don't see then you probably have to play a bit with the UI to display them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I also encountered similar problem. I defined a matrix as:

`Eigen::MatrixXf minor2x2 (2,2)`. When the matrix `minor2x2` was initialized like that :

```
minor2x2[0] = 1.0f;
minor2x2[1] = 1.0f;
minor2x2[2] = 1.0f;
minor2x2[3] = 1.0f;
```

The same error was triggered. The solution to the problem is to replace `minor2x2[i]` to `minor2x2(i)`. I think finding `Eigen::Matrix` perhaps is helpful.